# Data sent from arduino does not appear in database

Tags: php, database, arduino

Using Arduino and PHP for my school project and localhost. And we have this issue where we need to send our data from the serial monitor in Arduino to the database. However, we have no issues with our coding for both the PHP and the Arduino side and yet the data does not appear in the dB itself.

This is our PHP codes.
This code is used to connect to dB and insert data

```
<?php
//connecting to database
require('database.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$firstReading = $_GET['fsrReading'];
/*$secondReading = $_GET['fsrReading1'];
$thirdReading = $_GET['fsrReading2'];
$finalReading = $_GET['finalReading'];*/
$secondReading = 0;<
$thirdReading = 0;
$finalReading = 0;

 //insert Statement
$readings = "INSERT INTO readings
    SET 
    fsrReading = '$firstReading'";

$conn->query($readings);
?>
```

And this is the Arduino code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

char ssid[] = "*****";    //"TP-STUDENT"; //"Hongmi"; //"TP-SURF"; 
//"SINGTEL-14E7"; //  your network SSID (name)
char pass[] =  "******";   //"tB621011"; //"12341234";  //"sotnal88"; 
//"0016651495";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for 
WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;            // your network key Index number (needed only 
for WEP)
int fsrAnalogPin = 0; // FSR is connected to analog 0
/*int fsrAnalogPin1 = 1; // FSR is connected to analog 1
int fsrAnalogPin2 = 2;
int LEDpin = 3;  */    // connect Red LED to pin 11 (PWM pin)
int fsrReading = 0;      // the analog reading from the FSR resistor divider
/*int fsrReading1;
int fsrReading2;
int LEDbrightness;*/
int sensorValue = 0;
/*int finalReading;*/


int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
IPAddress server(*,*,*,*);    // name address for Google (using DNS)

WiFiClient client;



 void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP 
network:
status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  //printWifiStatus();

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:


  }

void loop(){
  client.stop();
  fsrReading = analogRead(fsrAnalogPin);
  //Serial.print("1st reading = "); 
  Serial.println(fsrReading);

  /*fsrReading1 = analogRead(fsrAnalogPin1);
  Serial.print("2nd reading = ");
  Serial.println(fsrReading1);

  fsrReading2 = analogRead(fsrAnalogPin2);
  Serial.print("3rd reading = ");
  Serial.println(fsrReading2);

  double finalReading =(fsrReading+fsrReading1+fsrReading2);

  Serial.print("Final Reading = ");
  Serial.println(finalReading);

  // we'll need to change the range from the analog reading (0-1023) down to the range
  // used by analogWrite (0-255) with map!
  if(finalReading > 2500){
  LEDbrightness = map(fsrReading, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  analogWrite(LEDpin, LEDbrightness);
  }    
  else analogWrite(LEDpin,LOW);*/


if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected to server");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.print("GET /connect.php?");
    //client.println("GET /connect.php?sensordata=666  HTTP/1.1");
    client.print("fsrReading=");
    client.print(fsrReading);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: ******");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    //client.println();
    client.stop();
}
else {
Serial.println("--> connection failed\n");
}
delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested the php script on a desktop first?

Comment: There is a stray `<` in `$secondReading = 0;<`.  Also try checking the PHP code in isolation from a normal browser and see if that inserts the data.  This allows you to work out which part isn't working.

Comment: @kks21199 what do you and how do you do that? We typed in the data into the url to force send a data into the database and it works.

Comment: @NigelRen we are currently testing the first reading only. Thats why our second reading= 0.

Comment: @Juju so the problem is your arduino side. Are you getting any success output in arduino?

Comment: @Juju try using your phone to access the webpage and see if that data is saved in database as well.

Comment: @kks21199 https://imgur.com/a/QmTFw48   errrrr and we are using localhost hahah xD

Comment: @Juju if you are using localhost, are you sure your arduino is resolving the links correctly? If your phone (connected to Sam network as your server) can't access the site, I don't think your arduino can either.

Comment: @kks21199 on phone can

Comment: print the HTTP response in Arduino.